# Rspec Suite Failing on OmniAuth Mock Auth Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, omniauth

My Rspec tests are all passing individually but are failing as the whole suite.

I have narrowed the issue down to using the mock omniauth hash describe in `spec/support/devise.rb`:

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = {
  "uid" => "1111",
  "provider" => "facebook",
  "credentials" => {
    "token" => "token",
    "secret" => "secret"
  },
  "extra" => {
    "raw_info" => {
      "name" => "Adam Waite",
      "username" => "adamjwaite",
      "email" => "adam@adam.com"
    }
  }
}

OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook, OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook])
```

When I inspect `OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]` just before the tests fails (using [pry](http://pryrepl.org)) it returns `:invalid_credentials` if run in the suite. If I run the same test in an individual test file it appears as it's displayed.

Here's the failing test in the registration method in my `UsersController`:

```
describe "GET :new" do
  describe "as an unauthenticated user with a facebook omniauth session" do
    before do
      session[:omniauth_facebook] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]
      get :new
    end
    specify { assigns[:registering_with_facebook].should == true }
    specify { assigns[:registering_with_twitter].should == false }
    specify { response.should be_success }
  end
end
```

It's also worth mentioning that the application function correctly too. I would just like the suite to pass.

Anyone shine any light on what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever a test works in isolation, but fails with other tests, you have a test ordering issue. Some earlier test is changing global state and leaving it that way, which negatively affects this test.

I've created a small tool to help me find ordering issues in my own suites: [rspec-search-and-destroy](https://github.com/shepmaster/rspec-search-and-destroy). It will take your test suite and bisect it until it finds the one test that is setting the bad global state. Of course, you can do this yourself by hand, but hopefully the tool can automate the drudgery.

Once you have found the earlier test, then you need to inspect it to figure out what global state is being set and how you can properly sandbox that change to just the test that needs it.

Comment: Thanks. Your gem directed me to my own stupidity in a spec that ran prior to the failing spec. I had done `OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = :invalid_credentials` to test failure and forgot to put it back for the other specs to use. Duh. Thanks!